# Google Php Oauth Login Error No system CA bundle could be found

Tags: php, oauth, ssl-certificate, ca

I am exactly following the example but get an error on 
$client->authenticate($_GET['Code']);
The code value is being returned but will not authenticate. The error is

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message ' No system CA bundle could be found in any of the the common system locations. PHP versions earlier than 5.6 are not properly configured to use the system's CA bundle by default. In order to verify peer certificates, you will need to supply the path on disk to a certificate bundle to the 'verify' request option: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/clients.html#verify. If you do not need a specific certificate bundle, then Mozilla provides a commonly used CA bundle which can be downloaded here (provided by the maintainer of cURL): https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bagder/ca-bundle/master/ca-bundle.crt. Once you have a CA bundle available on disk, you can set the 'openssl.cafile' PHP ini setting to point to the path to the file, allowing you to omit the 'verify' request option. See http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html for more information.' in /base/data/home/apps/s~solomon-1/1.388711045841969234/google-api-php-client/vendor/guzzlehttp/ringphp/src/Client/Cli in /base/data/home/apps/s~solomon-1/1.388711045841969234/google-api-php-client/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php on line 51

??

Comment: openssl.cafile="/solomonschariot_com/solomonschariot_com.ca-bundle"I have tried the php ini setting for just about every variety of path i.e.    openssl.cafile="/solomonschariot_com/solomonschariot_com.ca-bundle"

Answer (score 6):

Looking through [Google](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) and [Guzzle's](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) code you might need to specify where the certificate bundle can be found by doing something like the following when you setup the Google Client and before your `authenticate()` call:

```
$client->setHttpClient(new GuzzleHttp\Client(['verify'=>'path\to\your\cert-bundle']));
```

This will override the default behavior and let you specify where the bundle is.

You could also test that this is the right direction by setting `verify` to `false`:

```
$client->setHttpClient(new GuzzleHttp\Client(['verify'=>false]));
```

This will basically tell curl not to verify the host nor the peer.

Comment: Nope, tried both and even setting verify to false, neither worked

Comment: It was the absense of curl  in the default php on app engine

Comment: I have been trying to solve this on my own app for WEEKS. You're the king. This one worked for me: `$client->setHttpClient(new GuzzleHttp\Client(['verify'=>'path\to\your\cert-bundle']));`

Comment: Glad this helped someone. :-)

Answer (score 2):

App Engine Php requires curl to be expressly enabled in the php.ini file at the root directory with the ini line
extension = "curl.so"
Be careful with the releases, Confusing sets of oauth proceedures, and I found an update and it was only mentioned in the Readme of the download I thought was current.

Comment: Following option 3 in link worked for me (http://www.tomjepson.co.uk/enabling-curl-in-php-php-ini-wamp-xamp-ubuntu/)