# Can't access the Google Cloud Datastore with PHP code

Tags: php, gcloud

- I have installed the google cloud files with composer (terminal)
- export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='...'
- Received my .json key from gcloud which is in the very same directory as my code
- Made 3 entities in my google Datastore

All I'm trying to do:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
  use Google\Cloud\Datastore\DatastoreClient;
  putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=...');

  // Various checks
  if(isset($_POST["userId"]) && isset($_POST["password"])){
    $userId = $_POST["userId"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $datastore = new DatastoreClient(["..." => $projectId]);
    $key = $datastore->key($userId, $password);
    $entity = $datastore->lookup($key);
    if($entity != null){
      // do stuff...
    }
?>
```

The page loads fine it's just when I submit the form it crashes giving exceptions/errors stating it can't find the .json file or it can't verify my credentials.

**[Update]:** By placing the putenv() it seems the datastore object can be made but whenever I try to retrieve an entity using the lookup() function I get the following error code:

```sh
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\ServiceException' with message
 "No system CA bundle could be found in any of the the common system 
 locations. PHP versions earlier than 5.6 are not properly configured
 to use the system's CA bundle by default. In order to verify peer 
 certificates, you will need to supply the path on disk to a
 certificate bundle to the 'verify' request option:
 http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/clients.html#verify. 
 If you do not need a specific certificate bundle, then Mozilla provides a commonly used CA bundle which can be downloaded here (provided by the maintainer of cURL): 
 https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bagder/ca-bundle/master/ca-bundle.crt. 
 Once you have a CA bundle available on disk, you can set the 'openssl.cafile' PHP ini setting to point to the path to the file, allowing you to omit the 'verify' request option. 
 See http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html for more information."
```

I am very unfamiliar with what a CA bundle is or how exactly I am suppose to use it to solve the issue here.

Comment: Hi, could you include the error(s) that you are receiving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to set the env variable before as in [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries#setting_up_authentication)

```php
<?php
  putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=...');
  session_start();
  require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
  use Google\Cloud\Datastore\DatastoreClient;
  # ...
```

Comment: Thank you, this has allowed the datastore client object to be created but I still can't seem to retrieve any entities (I've updated my question showing the error code I keep receiving)

Comment: Regarding the error message, are you using PHP versions earlier than 5.6? If so, can you migrate to newer PHP versions?

Comment: I’m not entirely sure. In terminal my php version is 7.3.11 but in my app.yaml file within my directory which is used when deploying my app to gcloud it says, 'runtime: php55'

Comment: The error you see is similar to the one present in this GitHub thread, please take a look to the solution in https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php/issues/340#issuecomment-291552932

Comment: And also the other response in a StackOverflow thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/35569174/6003934

Comment: I tried the github link's answer but it didn't make a difference. I don't really understand the stackoverflow link's answer as I don't know how to download the CA bundle.

Comment: You have to download and use a certificate as in the thread. Or right away use a php version that supports the system CA bundle.

Comment: I’ve changed the app.yaml file to runtime: php56 and even php72 but when I deploy the app it says both versions aren’t supported

Comment: ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Invalid runtime 'php56' specified. Accepted runtimes are: [go, php, php55, python27, java, java7, java8, go111, go112, go113, java11, nodejs10, nodejs12, php72, php73, python37, python38, ruby25]

Comment: `ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: PHP 5.4 applications are prevented from being deployed to Google App Engine from any version of the SDK, including older ones. If you need to continue to deploy PHP 5.4 applications for compatibility reasons, you can request that your application be whitelisted for PHP 5.4 deployment by visiting...`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209918/discussion-between-wguida95-and-juancki).