# Access Google Cloud Storage from Local Env PHP

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am just trying to do a very simple `file_get_contents('gs://[bucket][file]');`

I am getting this error when I run locally.
`"\google\appengine\ext\cloud_storage_streams\CloudStorageStreamWrapper::stream_open" call failed`.

However, when I run it on my production env it works fine.

I know I am missing something with the setup, and I am just not sure what.

I have set the project `gcloud config set project PROJECT_ID`, set the account `gcloud config set account ACCOUNT`, and run `gcloud auth login`. Any ideas on what I am missing in my setup here?

---

I ran `composer install` , `composer require google/cloud`, I don't get any errors when including `use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;` I created the `service-account-keyfile` as an owner of the bucket. Set owners to full permissions. Ran this code...

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;
$storage = new StorageClient([
    'keyFilePath' => __DIR__ .'/../keys/appdocs-com.json',
]);
echo file_get_contents('gs://[myBucket][myFile]');
```

and I am still getting `...streamWrapper::stream_open" call failed`

I even tried the service builder approach.

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Google\Cloud\ServiceBuilder;
use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;

$gcloud = new ServiceBuilder([
    'keyFilePath' => __DIR__ .'/../keys/appdocs-com.json',
    'projectId' => 'appdocs-com',
]);

$storage = $gcloud->storage();
$bucket = $storage->bucket('test-appdocs-sendgrid-inbound');
$object = $bucket->object('4/envelope.json');
$stream = $object->downloadAsStream();
echo $stream->getContents();
```

this returns

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\ServiceException' with message 'No system CA bundle could be found in any of the the common system locations. PHP versions earlier than 5.6 are not properly configured to use the system's CA bundle by default. In order to verify peer certificates, you will need to supply the path on disk to a certificate bundle to the 'verify' request option: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/clients.html#verify. If you do not need a specific certificate bundle, then Mozilla provides a commonly used CA bundle which can be downloaded here (provided by the maintainer of cURL): https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bagder/ca-bundle/master/ca-bundle.crt. Once you have a CA bundle available on disk, you can set the 'openssl.cafile' PHP ini setting to point to the path to the file, allowing you to omit the 'verify' request option. See http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html for more information.' in /Users/thom/Engine/appdocs-com/vendor/google/cloud-core/RequestWrapper.php:241 Stack trac in /Users/thom/Engine/appdocs-com/vendor/google/cloud-core/RequestWrapper.php on line 241
```

I have my `runtime` at `php55`. Could that be preventing me from using `StorageClient` or `serviceBuilder`

Comment: You should ensure the gcloud and php installation and configuration on your development env match the production env

Comment: Shouldn't they match if I deployed that very app from the command line with `gcloud app deploy`?

Answer (score 2):

When outside the appengine environment, you will need to manually register the cloud storage stream wrapper to access files using the `gs://` protocol:

```
use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;

$storage = new StorageClient([
    'keyFilePath' => '/path/to/service-account-keyfile.json'
]);

$storage->registerStreamWrapper();
```

This example assumes you have [Google Cloud PHP](https://github.com/googlecloudplatform/google-cloud-php) installed.

More information is available in the [Google Cloud PHP docs](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.32.1/storage/storageclient?method=registerStreamWrapper).

To resolve the guzzle ssh error, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33837722/google-php-oauth-login-error-no-system-ca-bundle-could-be-found/33838098#33838098). **NOTE** that setting `verify` to `false` is not safe, and should only be used to test, never in production.

Comment: I updated my answer to show what I have tried... have you actually got this working?

Comment: I updated mine as well. The error you see now is related to your installation of curl not being configured correctly to handle secure requests. It's a fairly common problem in local development servers, and can be resolved permanently by setting the `openssl.cafile` setting in your `php.ini` file to point at a valid certificate.

Comment: I was reading through https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/config/php_ini it looks like they turn curl off. I don't know if there is a way around this.

Answer (score 0):

As @jdp mentioned in his answer, the error I was getting was related to my installation of curl.

So I looked at Google's php_ini docs to see if I could set the openssl.cafile. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/config/php_ini

If you want to use Google Storage Client you need to change from standard to flexible env.
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/quickstart

Then read through cloud storage docs to see how to download dependencies for the API usage: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries

Once you have set up your flex env and gathered dependencies, you can then follow these directions to set up the connection.

Set up a service account key In Google Cloud Console:

- Select "your-project"->IAM & ADMIN-> Service Accounts.
- Click the "Create Service Account" button.
- Assign role (in my case I assigned the role "owner" since this service account was specific to my local development), mark the checkbox "Furnish New Private Key".

This just downloaded your "service-account-keyfile.json"

Then in the code initiate Cloud Storage like so:

```
use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;

$storage = new StorageClient([
    'keyFilePath' => '/path/to/service-account-keyfile.json'
]);

$storage->registerStreamWrapper();
```

You can now retrieve bucket data like you would from the production env.

```
echo file_get_contents('gs://[Bucket][File]');
```

Make sure you have set the bucket permissions to allow the previously selected role to access the bucket.

However, I would still love to find a way to set up a local environment with with php standard that can interact with `gs://[bucket]/[file]`.